# How to get last inserted row in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005

How can i get Last inserted row when in table there is no `Uniqueidentifier or identity` column.

I am waiting of your good idea's.

Comment: Although this is just my opinion, I believe that every table should have a unique ID, even if it's not utilized by the application itself. Doing things this way would solve your problem

Comment: Unless the table has no indexes you can't. Can I ask why you would want the last record?

Comment: @saret when the Uniqueidentifier is used it still isn't possible to get the last record

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some way of being able to identify the ordering of the rows to determine that. Something like a "creation date" or IDENTITY column.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. A table consists of an unordered set of rows*. If you need to know, for instance, when a row was inserted, you need to add that information into the table definition (by adding a new column) and populating it appropriately.

*even in the face of a clustered index, it's healthier to *always* consider a table as being an unordered set of rows. A clustered index is useful, but it doesn't guarantee any particular physical ordering (As in Martin's comment to this answer)

Comment: Rows within a single page aren't necessarily ordered by clustered index the list of row offsets is but the offsets themselves can be out of order. i.e. if a full page has rows with key values `1,2,3,5,6` and then `1` is deleted and `4` inserted it won't reorganize the whole page it will just stick `4` where `1` was and update the list of row offsets.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get last row from  table without uniqueIdentifier or identity then you can use insert trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe you can. You'll need some kind of identifier to extract data. ID, DateTime.. anything that will always be different from the others.

Answer (score 0):

if you insert something by stored procedure you should use SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() which will return the last identity value created in the current session, but it will also limit it to your current scope.
By this usage you will not get last inserted identity which can be caused by trigger.

Have that in mind if you will use result for operation of insertion inside same or called procedure.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @IDs TABLE(id int)

insert into TableName(TableID, TableRowValue)
output inserted.TableID into @IDs
values(857, 'Test');
```

-- The inserted identity will be in the `@IDs` table variable

Comment: If this was the context of the question, you wouldn't even need the output table, would you